# How to attach to express process using VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm running an express API using gulp-nodemon and I want to debug the received requests using VS Code.

My problem is: I can't attach to a running process. In my `launch.json` configuration, I don't want to start-attach, I would like to just attach to a running instance (which is managed by gulp).

My VS Code `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858 // tried to use 3000 (express port), but failed too
        }
    ]
}
```

Using port 3000 it fails immediately without showing anything. Using port 5858 it fails with the message:

> Cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 10000 ms).

Answer (score 0):

I run my application in debug mode using:

```
node --inspect app
```

And my configuration uses port 9229:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

<sup>Port 5858 used be the port for the now deprecated `--debug` option</sup>